# Creating Library Playlist using Apple Music API and getting 400 - Bad Request?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, apple-music

As per this documentation shared link below,

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/create_a_new_library_playlist

I'm able to get developer token and music user token but I am getting error for 'Invalid Request Body' (400 Bad Request).

This is the function that I'm using to create apple music playlist.

```
func createAppleMusicPlaylist() {
    
    let playlistURL = URL(string: Config.appleCreatePlaylist)!
    var playlistRequest = URLRequest(url: playlistURL)
    playlistRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    let params = ["name"        : kPlaylistName,
                  "description" : kPlaylistDesc]

    playlistRequest.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)
    
    playlistRequest.addValue("Bearer \(DeveloperToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    playlistRequest.addValue("\(UserToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Music-User-Token")
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: playlistRequest) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("\(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            return
        }
        
        if let data = data {
            let json = try? JSONDecoder().decode(AppleCreatePlaylistModel.self, from: data)

        }
    }.resume()
}
```

API Response:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "id": "X4IK3UU6LYGGRSQ6U2KQANL63A",
            "title": "Invalid Request Body",
            "detail": "Unable to parse request body",
            "status": "400",
            "code": "40007"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please suggest required body parameters.
Thanks!

Comment: What's your code?

Comment: Try with: `let params: [String: Any] = ["attributes: ["name": "someName", "description": "someDescription"]]`. I think you are bypassing the `attributes` level, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/libraryplaylistcreationrequest

Comment: Hi @Larme! Could you plz help me in adding track required body parameters, facing same issue as above. For reference I'm using below link and I created body parameters as follows:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/add_tracks_to_a_library_playlist

{
"id": "<song_id>",
"type": "library-songs"
}

Comment: Same error. Read the "HTTP Body" part. It goes to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/libraryplaylisttracksrequest, so it needs `{"tracks":...}`, at top level., then it needs `{"data": [...]}`, , then "id" & "type". So it should be `{"tracks": {"data": [{"id": "songId", "type": "library-songs"}]}}`. Read the doc step by step, level by level.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the API documentation, [Create a New Library Playlist](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/create_a_new_library_playlist), and follow the HTTP Body part that causing issue in your case.

> HTTP Body
> LibraryPlaylistCreationRequest
> The POST request containing the name, tracks and parent playlist folder for the playlist to be added.

Now, let's check [`LibraryPlaylistCreationRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/libraryplaylistcreationrequest):

> Properties
>
> - **attributes**
>    LibraryPlaylistCreationRequest.Attributes
>    (Required) 
>    A dictionary that includes strings for the name and
>   description of the new playlist.
> - **relationships**
>    LibraryPlaylistCreationRequest.Relationships
>    An optional key
>   including tracks for the new playlist.

So, body should like this, at this point:

```
{
    "attributes": ...,    //Required
    "relationships": ...  //Optional
}
```

Let's see now [`LibraryPlaylistCreationRequest.Attributes`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/libraryplaylistcreationrequest/attributes):

> Properties
>
> - **description**
>    string
>    The description of the playlist.
> - **name**
>    string
>    (Required) The name of the playlist.description
>    string

So, now, the JSON should look like this (I skipped the `relationships` part since you don't use it):

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "name": "playlist name",
        "description": "playlist description"
    }
}
```